# How to record mpeg2ts video with camera

Tags: android

I have tried to generate MPEG2TS via MediaRecorder with camera.
My code is following.

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8); // OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG2TS
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/rec1.ts");
```

But, after recoding is finished, generated file(rec1.ts) is always 0 byte.
For other OutputFormat like "OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4", it works fine.

I don't know why it does not work..